# Is it possible to replace Chmod with Explorer's properties in windows?

Tags: windows, filesystems, chmod, filesystemobject, icacls

I need to make SSH with PEM file.
But i constantly recieve errors from aws about pem file which is not secured enough.
I tried to perfom chmod 400, chmod 600 on WSL, and also tried to replace chmod with icacls.exe but none of that worked.
I was wondering is it possible to change properties in Windows Explorer which can replace chmod.
And if yes what properties should allow and dany to make it somehow similar to Linux Chmod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the WSL can't run chmod at any windows location.
It works only if file located at linux home direction.
Like this:

```
C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\[username]
```

If file will be located here all chomod commands should work fine.
Also keep in mind that folder name may be different for different Linux versions in my case it's : `CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc`